# Weakness & Lack of Strength

Tags: strength

I want a great physique, instead of good, for this I need a lot of hard work, good food & Strength. But the problem is that my stamina is not so good, because of that i am unable to lift weight & work hard, because doing this causes weakness & BLACKOUT. Dark circles also occurs under eyes. I eat 10-12 chapati(s) in a meal or 400-500gm of rice with veggies or cereals. But the problem is same. Can you tell me something to gain strength, stamina & muscles..

Answer (score 3):

If that's your whole diet, then that's the reason you are having problems.  The diet is very unbalanced, and does not support your desire to get strong and have a great physique.

- [Eat enough Protein](http://gregnuckols.com/2014/03/12/the-three-laws-of-protein/): 1.8g/kg body weight.  If you are vegetarian, you'll have to get creative.  Oats and quinoa have a decent amount of protein in them.  If you can eat meat and eggs, I recommend it highly.
- Eat fruits and vegetables: many of your micronutrients you kneed are contained in these.  Fruits and green vegetables are very nutrient rich.
- Eat enough fat to support metabolism, but not much more than that: .16g / kg absolute minimum.  A little more than that would be good.
- The rest of your food from carbohydrates.

The bottom line is that your food should be coming from a variety of different sources.  Just chapati and rice robs your body of what it needs to function properly.

Additionally, you'll have to be ramp up your activity a little slower so that your body has a chance to catch up.  Do not neglect conditioning work as well.  In fact, it might be a good idea to get a physical to see where you are starting from.  For your sake, I might suggest starting with conditioning work so that your heart and lungs can get used to working harder before you transition to weights.  The last thing you want to do is black out with a bar over your chest.

A question for you: did your heart race uncontrollably at any time during exercise?  If so, that is a sign something a bit more concerning is going on and might require you to get that checked out by a doctor.

Answer (score -1):

You have to change your habits gradually and start from some reasonable level of strain.

You should never come even close to blackout.

You should eat each 2 - 3 hours, you should sleap enough and have enough rest.

You should add to your food also a lot of meat - you should eat balanced food full of proteins, sugars and fats and plenty of vitamins and minerals.

Comment: I disagree on the meal frequency. Eating a handful of food every 2-3 hours may work for some (me included) and won't for others. It is, however, not necessary. Neither is meat, although it makes things a hell of a lot more convenient.

Comment: Needs more effort